# Long.compare works on Android<API19 despite docu says it should not

Tags: android, lint

I came across a Lint warning pointing me that following code won't work on Android < API 19, but actually it works, and I think it's because the compiler is inlining the call, am I right, or is there another reasson?:

Long.compare(qli2.getDateAdded(), qli1.getDateAdded());

Also in the documentation of the method it says since java 1.7, but it works on Android API 16 with java 1.6

Comment: Well, the implementation is just ternary operation `lhs < rhs ? -1 : (lhs == rhs ? 0 : 1)` :-)

Comment: It can be just a compiler optimization, it is easy to inline such methods.

Answer (score 0):

The magic behind this is the D8 tool, which desugars language features depending on your minSdk level.

D8 lacks a bit of documentation IMHO, but [this article of Jake Wharton](https://jakewharton.com/d8-library-desugaring/) should give you more insights.